# Load SecondViewController automatically using Segue

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, swift4, segue

How to load `SecondViewController` simultaneously with `ViewController` inside `viewDidLoad()` method?

Segue's type is `Sheet`.

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "secondVC", sender: self)
    }

    func prepareforSegue(segue: NSStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let identifier = segue.identifier, identifier == "secondVC" {
            _ = segue.destinationController as? SecondViewController
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "secondVC", sender: self)
```

won't work inside `viewDidLoad` consider wraping it inside a Dispatch-after or inside a bool flag in `viewDidAppear`

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline:.now() + 2 ) {
   self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "secondVC", sender: self)
}
```

**OR**

```
var once = true
override func viewDidAppear() {
   super.viewDidAppear()
   if once {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "secondVC", sender: self)
        once = false
   }
}
```

Comment: i think delay in seconds won't be accurate , try other option

Comment: Does `once` serve like terminator? I mean, it stops segue's session.

Comment: it will show the sheet only once as when you return from a present  above that VC  , viewDidAppear is called